# How many candies of one color does it take to make Odus fall?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

In the new Dreamworld levels, there is an owl named Odus that balances on a moon. Making matches of one color on one side of the moon will cause the balance to tip and eventually Odus will fall (prematurely ending the level).

In my playing, I have noticed that only colors removed from the board (ie not the 'boxed' candies) will tilt him one way or another. I have also noticed that getting 'bigger' (ie four in a row) sets will make him tilt more. All of this has led me to the assumption that he takes a static number of removed candies till he falls and I lose the game.

My question is how many candies does it take for him to fall? Or, if I'm wrong in my assumptions, what are the exact conditions for him to fall?

Comment: It seems this would be useful information because if you know he's +3 left (for instance) you might have +5 left remaining as wiggle room.

Comment: Certain levels seem to be more unstable while others aren't stable. Best thing to do is just when it's gone, use as many combos as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed imbalance varies from level to level. It's based on the number of candies removed from the board.

In [this wiki](http://candycrush.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Dreamworld_Levels) you can find this exact number for each level.

EDIT:

For example this is the wiki page for the level 151:

http://candycrush.wikia.com/wiki/Level_151/Dreamworld

Scroll down to the "Moon scale" section to see how big imbalance is needed to get Odus fall.

Comment: The wiki is definitely a useful source, but I can't seem to find where they tell you what the imbalance is for a given level. Can you edit your answer with an example?

Comment: @Bob2Chiv Added an example.

Answer (score 3):

I concur with your assertion that the amount of tilt is "candies" based.  You can easily test this with a Color Bomb and you'll find that if you were leaning far in the opposite the direction the Color Bomb can still lose it for you (so no turn based).

Generally speaking, I've concluded from testing that it takes ~12 candies for him to lean to the "danger zone" where he starts hopping frantically.  At that point it may take as few as one candy to push him over the edge, but I'll say 3 since from my testing I was mostly just matching 3 at a time.

[As I've mentioned elsewhere](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150806/21619) the Moon Scale won't tilt during a Moonstruck Event, and you also can't fail if it was the last move of the round and you finish the other objectives.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it does take a static number of candies for Odus to fall, but that this number varies by level.

Sometimes it takes 6, other times it takes 12 (or more?). The key point here it that for a given level, that amount will be the same.

So, if you're having trouble with a level, it may help you to 'waste' a life figuring out how much leeway you have until he falls off.